# How to expand a wpf window to the left (animated) to show more content/options

Tags: c#, wpf, expand

I'm working on an app which is a small screen and it will have a button on the top left side with an arrow that indicates the window can be expanded to the left and see more options.

I already investigated and all I found are options to the left side panel like in windows but what I need is to show an actual custom screen that is attached to the one from where it was expanded.

Answer (score 0):

"what I need is to show an actual custom screen that is attached to the one from where it was expanded."

That would be a window next to your original.

You could new up another window and show it to the left of your current one.

If you then animate the width of that you will find that is jumpy. Animating a windows width smoothly is a problem because the windows system wants to get involved in window size changes and it makes the animation judder.

The way round that is to have the window there (shown) already but totally transparent and with a $null background so it isn't hit testable. You will need to set style=none on the window so it has absolutely no chrome.

You can then animate the width of the root panel (grid) within that window. Which can be animated smoothly, no problem.

Your new window will have no title so it'll be more of a separate panel.

Or you could have your main window with no chrome and null background so it covers the area you want to animate into but is totally invisible. Put a grid with two columns in it and your initial content in column 1.  Animate a panel in column 0 as I described.

If this does not suit you then maybe you should reconsider your requirement and have a flyout of some sort within the one original window. Animate a panel in from one side. You will probably have seen this on web sites and apps. I would describe this as the "usual" approach.